# Postgresql combine row with null items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
ts                    itemA         itemB         itemC         
2018-02-03 12:00:00   1             null          null          
2018-02-03 12:00:00   null          2             6
2018-02-03 12:00:00   null          2             4
2018-02-03 12:01:00   null          3             6
2018-02-03 12:01:00   null          2             4
```

want output look like

```
ts                    itemA         itemB         itemC         
2018-02-03 12:00:00   1             2             5
2018-02-03 12:01:00   null          3             6
2018-02-03 12:01:00   null          2             4
```

which i try using group by time & itemB, and getting the average of itemC.
but cant figure out how to combine the null item

```
select ts, mode() within group (order by itemA), itemB, avg(itemC) group by ts, itemB;
```

Comment: What `itemB` value does the `NULL` value get assigned?  Say there were was anther row with `NULL` at `2018-02-03 12:01:00`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
SELECT ts,
MAX(IFNULL(itemA, 0)) AS itemA,
IFNULL(itemB, 0) AS itemB,
AVG(itemC)
FROM t
GROUP BY ts, IFNULL(itemB, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `itemB` from the aggregation.  Perhaps:

```
select ts, mode() within group (order by itemA) as itemA,
       max(itemB) as itemB, avg(itemC) as itemC
from t
group by ts;
```

EDIT:

Formally, you can do:

```
select ts, mode() within group (order by itemA) as itemA,
       itemBB, avg(itemC) as itemC
from (select t.*, coalesce(itemB, max(itemB) over (partition by ts)) as itemBB,
      from t
     ) t
group by ts, itemBB;
```

This works for your sample data but I'm not sure it is the logic you really want.

Comment: Thanks! coalesce is exactly what i want